# How can I add and get value of a button in angular?

Tags: html, angularjs

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">A </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">B </button>
```

How can I add a default value to my button A. Like I wanted button A to have a value of "OK" and B a value of "BYE". So if button A is clicked then I am able to get the value "OK". How can I achieve that in angularjs?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use ng-init to set a initial value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hard code the value of your button like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="callFun('OK')">A </button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="callFun('BYE')">B </button>
```

and in your script add a function like this:

```
$scope.callFun = function(value){
if(value && value==='OK'){
// Do stuff for OK
}else{
// Do stuff for BYE
}
}
```

Working Code here :

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="callFun('OK')">A </button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="callFun('BYE')">B </button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.callFun = function(value){
        if(value && value==='OK'){
          alert(value)
          // Do stuff for OK
        }else{
          alert(value)
          // Do stuff for BYE
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using ng-init and ng-click.

```
  <button type="button" ng-init="btnname=OK"  ng-click="callA()"class="btn btn-default">A </button>
  <button type="button" ng-init="btnname=BYE" ng-click="callB()" class="btn btn-default">B </button>
```

Example link :

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-click

Refer the manual for more : 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick[enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Comment: how will I be able to get an "OK" value using $scope.nameHere

Comment: You can access that value in your respective scope using {{btnname}}

Comment: thanks 5eeker, great point. Looking Sudhir's answer below better suits my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use onClick() function and inside these function you assign these value i.e Ok and Bye